# Camera View not showing up

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, camera

I'm trying to get a camera view for a camera app to show. After messing with the setup camera view code without success. I think it has something to do with my GLKView setup code. The UIView in the storyboard shows up on the app but its blank (white). I don't get any errors.

I'm building this for at least iOS 7.0.

I added both the createGLKView and the setupCameraView blocks just incase!

EDIT: I forgot to set an outlet to the UIView. It shows now, but the camera view is black. My background is white so I know that the camera view is showing up black.

```
func createGLKView() {

    if (self.context != nil) {

        return

    }

    self.context = EAGLContext(API: EAGLRenderingAPI.OpenGLES2)
    //.init(API:EAGLRenderingAPI.OpenGLES2)
    var view: GLKView = GLKView(frame: self.bounds)
    //.init(frame: bounds.self)

    view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing(2) | UIViewAutoresizing(5)

    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints()
    view.context = self.context
    view.contentScaleFactor = 1.0
    view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat.Format24

    self.insertSubview(view, atIndex: 0)

    glkView = view

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &renderBuffer)
    glBindRenderbuffer(GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), renderBuffer)
    coreImageContext = CIContext(EAGLContext: self.context)
    EAGLContext.setCurrentContext(self.context)

    println("GLKView setup")

}

func setupCameraView() {

    self.createGLKView()

    var possibleDevices: NSArray = AVCaptureDevice.devicesWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

    //var device: AVCaptureDevice = possibleDevices.firstObject as! AVCaptureDevice

    var device: AVCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    /*
    if device != true {

        println("device returned!")
        return

    }
    */

    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()

    // Loop through all the capture devices on this phone
    for camera in devices {
        // Make sure this particular device supports video
        if (camera.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)) {
            // Finally check the position and confirm we've got the back camera
            if(camera.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back) {

                device = camera as! AVCaptureDevice

            }
        }
    }


    imageDetectionConfidence = 0.0

    var session: AVCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    self.captureSession = session
    session.beginConfiguration()
    self.captureDevice = device
    /*
    for camera in possibleDevices {

        if camera.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back {

            device = camera as! AVCaptureDevice
            println("back camera selected!")
            break

        }

    }
    */
    var error: NSError?
    /*
    var input: AVCaptureDeviceInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDevice(device, error: &error) as! AVCaptureDeviceInput
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
    session.addInput(input)
    */

    if let input: AVCaptureDeviceInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDevice(device, error: &error) as? AVCaptureDeviceInput {

        session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
        session.addInput(input)

    }

    var dataOutput: AVCaptureVideoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    dataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

    //dataOutput.videoSettings = NSDictionary(object: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA), forKey: kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String) as [NSObject: AnyObject]

    dataOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]

    dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())

    session.addOutput(dataOutput)

    self.stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
    session.addOutput(self.stillImageOutput)

    var connection: AVCaptureConnection = (dataOutput.connections as NSArray).firstObject as! AVCaptureConnection

    connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait

    if device.flashAvailable {

        device.lockForConfiguration(nil)
        device.flashMode = AVCaptureFlashMode.Off
        device.unlockForConfiguration()

        if device.isFocusModeSupported(AVCaptureFocusMode.ContinuousAutoFocus) {

            device.lockForConfiguration(nil)
            device.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusMode.ContinuousAutoFocus
            device.unlockForConfiguration()

        }

    }

    session.commitConfiguration()

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the code is correct, you could try to bring your subview to the front. I've found that sometimes when adding a new subview it isn't always shown above the others and gets hidden behind them.

```
self.bringSubviewToFront(view)
```

EDIT: It might help for others to know what iOS version you are programming for.

Comment: Have you been able to get other views to work in your project besides the camera?

Comment: I would think some sort of linking would be going on between the camera setup code and the GLKView but the only thing I see is `self.createGLKView()`.

Comment: What other views can I try? I have log checks and everything is linking up nicely (back camera connected, flash toggle works, session input added, dataOutputs added, etc)

Comment: If it helps, my code is a direct obj-c to swift translation of the IPDFCameraViewController open source code.

Comment: So it was a silly mistake: I didnt set an outlet to the UIView, but now the camera view comes up black. My background is white so I know its the camera view that is black.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to find the issue! Good luck with your app.

Comment: Would you have any idea as to why I'm gettin just black rather than an active camera view? So close!!!

Comment: Since you're using the Interface Builder, did you double-check to make sure you linked the camera view with the respective view in the IB (if you created a dummy camera view there)? Also, I know you're probably not, but if you're using the simulator it might be because of that.

Comment: I typically don't use the IB, so I do everything programmatically.

Comment: I'm testing it on my phone. The IB layout is basically a UIView inside a ViewController and all the camera setup is in the UIView, with the exception of "starting" the camera, which is in the ViewController. So I'm expecting the UIView to pop the camera view, unless there's another Storyboard component I need to be dragging in there?

Comment: Are you sure you're starting the camera when the camera view shows? It's possible to pop up the view without firing anything. Make sure the function/action (like didMoveToView) is linked to fire off the function to start up the camera since you probably set the camera up when the user desires to go to the camera.

Comment: Otherwise, it's kind of hard to understand the complete idea without seeing the project...  I don't want to ask you for it since I know how I'd feel about sharing my code.

Comment: Well right now, it's a swift copy of an open source project and nothing else. If you don't mind taking a look at it, I can send it to you? Let me know.

Comment: I figured it out. This is a lesson to me to never underestimate the power of spelling errors. My captureOutput block had a variable call of didOutputSampleBuffer and it was spelled didOutputSameBuffer. I'm guessing since it wasnt a variable instance/name and it was in a function call, it wasn't flagging any errors neither while running nor not running. Thanks miniluigi008 for helping me tackle such a silent but deadly problem!

Comment: I don't think I would have found that either! My dad still programs and he had a similar issue with the Swift log function and the appendNewLine argument. He had a spelling error so it ended up printing his log statements like tuples ("text", true)... We couldn't figure out what it was for the longest time.